# Android ViewPager Gallery

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a view pager to show a list of images, it works fine but the main issue is that when I swipe between images, there is some kind of fading between images.

for example if I have 5 pictures and the first one is visible when i swipe the second one is visible directly.
if i decided to swipe faster, it shows white screen then the image appears "moving from first to third quickly - as example".

I think the fragment is being recycled - is there any way to avoid this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell with no details on your implementation, but just to answer your last question (I'm not sure if it will necessarily solve your problem) - if you are using a fragments in your ViewPager and are currently using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, you can switch to a FragmentPagerAdapter, which will keep the fragments in memory (although it will of course use more memory, so you might not want to do it if you have a large number of fragments in your ViewPager).  You can also specify how many offscreen pages for the ViewPager to keep using

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

In the above case it would keep 2 pages on each side of the currently viewed page.  Sorry, I would have confirmed the specific problem with you before posting this answer, but I don't have the status yet :(